Ideal M in polynomial rings.
I have a problem that i don't know how to get started on.
Problem:
Find an ideal $M$ in the ring $\mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $\langle X^2-2\rangle\subsetneq M\subsetneq\mathbb{R}[X]$
Solution attempt:
We see that $X^2-2$ is not irreducible since it has two roots. Then $\langle X^2-2\rangle$ cannot be a maximal ideal and thus  $\mathbb{R}[X]/\langle X^2-2\rangle$ is not a field. I have no idea how to proceed though. Any advice will be appreciated - even full solutions. Thank you in advance

take the principal ideal generated by any factor of $X^2-2$.

I am shamefully copying the comment of Just a User:
$M= \langle X+\sqrt{2}\rangle$ or $M=\langle X-\sqrt{2}\rangle.$

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Take $\langle x+\sqrt{2}\rangle$. Then $\langle x^2-2\rangle \subseteq \langle x+\sqrt{2}\rangle$
because $x+\sqrt{2}\mid x^2-2$. The containment is strict because $\langle x+\sqrt{2}\rangle$ contains polynomials of degree 1, e.g. $x+\sqrt{2}$. Moreover, $\langle x+\sqrt{2}\rangle\subsetneq \mathbb{R}[x]$ because it does not contain a unit.
